# Capturing next value after random number of words

Tags: javascript, regex

I need create regex to capture the total value of a table it this disposition:

```
0920 1/3 FERIAS PAGAS MES ANTERIO 6,28 0,00 157.906,02
```

I need catch the 157.906,02.. which is the 3 number after the text.

So, i'm trying like this -> http://regexr.com/3cill

But is not working. I want find the 0920, ignore the number (sometimes doesn't exist) and name, then jump 2 numbers and catch the next. In my regex, i'm finding the 0920, but when i try to find the next number (sometimes doesn't exist) and the name, the regex is jumping to much.

Some examples:

```
0230 AJUDA DE CUSTO 10 0,00 7.144,85
0305 DIF. DE COMISSOES 1 0,00 260,00
```

In this cases, i need 7.144,85 and 260,00.. but the 1/3 before the name doesn't exist.

Update -

I was able to create this regex http://regexr.com/3cilr, but i have this feeling that i can do this better.

Thanks.

Comment: try `.*0920\s([\d\s]+)\s`

Comment: @AvinashRaj That will work just for the first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
/\b0(?:920|230|305)\s[\w.\/\s]+?\s(?:[\d,.]+\s){2}([\d,.]+)/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nU5qB8/1)

Comment: That's working really good. Can i ask a question? Is it possible to make the regex optionally? Because if the number doesn't exist, the match[1] will thrown an error.

Comment: Sorry didn't get, which number may not exist? I think you can check output of match for invalid input.

Comment: The whole phrase may not exist in some documents, so i would like to return "null" if doesn't exist.. currently the regex is throwing an error if the phrase.

Comment: regex won't throw error, just check return value of `match()` function and then use match[1]

Comment: if the phrase wont exist will thrown an error @anubhava

Comment: You should show your code in question so that I can suggest you a fix

Comment: Hei anubhava, that's a example: http://regexr.com/3cio3 change the 920 for 000.. if the text doesnt have 000 the regular expression will show timeout.. that's making my script stop.. do you know how avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100612/discussion-between-anubhava-and-celoxxx).